# How to iterate the object array only if boolean condition false in angular?

Tags: angular

I have two Json file below I attached, if one Json file boolean value false the corresponding another Json value field data need to show in the table format.

So if boolean value is false corresponding it is need to iterate in table

First Json file

```
    "gmbAuditData": [{
        "gmbtitle": [{
                "id": 1,
                "done": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "done": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "done": "Yes"
            }
        ],
        "gmbcategory": [{
                "id": 1,
                "done": "Yes"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "done": "No"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "done": "No"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "done": "No"
            }
        ]
        
    }]
}
```

**Second Json file**

[image]

**It needs to iterate only false **

It needs to come like this table format

[image]

It needs to come like this table
[image]

Comment: Which boolean value???

Comment: In first JSON file gmbauditdata.gmbtitle.done = false, it corresponding second Json ID field data needs to be iterated. Only iterate if condition false otherwise not iterate